# Related to Build.xml in Ant

Tags: ant, build.xml

What is the use of `TargetNameSpace` attribute in ant?

Comment: An example of what you're referring to would be helpful.

Comment: which ant task are you using in which this appeared?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have something to do with web services? I think I have used a similar attribute when working with axis web services.

```
<axis-java2wsdl classpathref="classpath" output="${wsdl.dir}/abc.wsdl" location="${service.url}" namespace="myns" classname="${serviceInterface}">
    <mapping namespace="http://impl.app" package="${serviceInterface}" />
</axis-java2wsdl>
```

Not sure if this is even useful, still posting it in case it helps.